# How to set the size of my application the same as an image

Tags: java, css, swing, windowbuilder

I uploaded an image of my java application below.

Problem:
I'm currently trying to make a login screen with a premade image as the background. I highlighted the actual size the background image which should also be the size of the application window. You can see that the login field is also out of place because its corresponding to the application window. 
This is probably because I'm using

```
Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

to set the size of the window.

My question is, how do I make the size of my application border the image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to set the size of my application the same as an image

Add your image to a JLabel using an ImageIcon. Then add the label to the frame and pack() the frame.

You can then set the layout manager of the JLabel and add other components to the label.

Answer (score 0):

If your panel is not yet visible:

```
Image im = ...; // your image
JPanel jp = ...;// panel where you draw your image
jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(im.getWidth(null), im.getHeight(null)));
```

Comment: Don't use setPreferredSize(). If you are going to custom paint an image on your panel, then the image should be a property of the panel and you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size of the image so all the logic is self contained in the custom class.